# typescript ReturnType is "any" if parameter type is "never"

Tags: typescript

short story

```
const abc = (a:never):number=>1
    
type a = ReturnType< typeof abc> //any

const abc2 = (a:number, b:never):number=>1

type a2 = ReturnType< typeof abc2> //any
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgI2DAvDAFHAXGApgN1wCcBKHAVwFsFiUA+ARgFgAoVqATwAdd5UYASrijkiYACrdcAHhiceIAGbwkdVq1CRYiYACZ+mCtWIAaGAhwFiZMFRpF6zNi3m84+tEJFjJPWa6UVPTogA)

ReturnType is any if any of the types of the parameters is never, is there anyway to overcome this?

long story (in case you are curious about the use case)

I have a utility type that prevents undefined for partial object member, empty object or excess object member which work perfectly

```
type _NoExcessEmptyUndefined<M, T> = M extends T
    ? keyof M extends keyof T
        ? keyof M extends never
            ? never
            : undefined extends M[keyof M]
            ? never
            : M
        : never
    : never

type something = {a?:number,b:boolean,c:string}

const abc = <M extends something>(data:_NoExcessEmptyUndefined<M,something>):number=>1

const emptyObject = {}
const undefinedPartial = {a:undefined,b:true,c:"1"}
const excessMember = {b:true,c:"1",d:1}

abc(emptyObject) // error if empty object
abc(undefinedPartial) // error if partial member is undefined
abc(excessMember) // error if excessMember

const success1 = {b:true,c:"1"}
const success2 = {a:1, b:true,c:"1"}

abc(success1) // no error
abc(success2) // no error

type haha = ReturnType<typeof abc> // haha is any <-- problem
type hihi = Parameters<typeof abc>[0] // hihi is never
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA+gcgewKIA8DGEDOmkFsygCqAdgCYQBmAlsRKQDwCyANFACoB8UAvFI1BBTAIZTOwCwAKACQAfigBrCCAQU+AoSNJilKtWynS5i5avWDhoqLQBuEAE6Gj82w6fSAXFACuZSjToNS20+AG1dM0YAXXcXCDtHGSMvRicvV0TPa3i3SSlQSChMBFwIYAALGgBzHigAbwBDWQ9ib1wAIwdmdo92hAQAGwgG4mY0D0xge2qAXykpNARiSagG9rRapiCtMWLSiuqOAApSBuAGj3hkdCwcfCI-aloGFj2yyuIqjgBKFrbO+zcDgARnmkkWy2AAnuIAA8u0AFYQNBQ3h1ObgpYrXzkJ50AAKDXswCoDQGtUaHhx-me3Q8U28EDGHgARMCWRiIStBBhsIwIB0HBSegymeM2SzmKQPMCMVI1mgjgKCHDEcjgN8oAB6LUCez2BD2KBUNTK0BQBBqlHy9ZHal40iE4mkgaanV6g1Gk1QMBEklk41ie0BUg2xU8278wX2N26hye42mm58gUAsFcqGYbxoXmYYHC+n2RnMiWcrGZ7O5gBMFIuwNYIqLYtZ7LlkgVRyzOduwNj1gQHsNYc7lduVb7xAH8aHeVnBWg5Qai9qACUyt57MQ2OAIPR52YFVx3Yvl1QxCMQFB6ABaa8+g3tIa4MHzqCVSq1J0NfYOTB7ncHusHChAADFE2q6u+VCBtkCRAA)

Comment: I suggest filing this as an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues); it is surprising behavior and I couldn't find an existing issue mentioning it.  It seems that while `(a: never)=>0` is assignable to  `(...args:any)=>any`, it is not assignable to `(...args:any)=>infer R` in a conditional type.  In practice I think that parameter lists with `never` in them are not very useful so it's hardly ever a big deal but it should probably be tracked.

Comment: issue opened: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this gives `any` in your case, but you can write your own version of `ReturnType` which works correctly:

```
type MyReturnType<F extends Function> = F extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? R : never;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKFgFcBOA7AKuCAeAYlBAB7AToAmAzlPsugMbACWA9ugHxQC8tRp5alAAUAOnEBDVAHMqALijN0AMwiooAQQCUPLktXr4UAPxQjC9BABuagNwBYAFBOG7KsCgSARgx4iJFtZqWhbIALZearpQAIxOTgD0CVDo4ZGoTqCQnn5wiCgY2JC4WRCsyp4+HPGOrujulQwATH7CASlpagA0UF6BNqghHRFR3Fxxzo5Jw+mZOJ4tvHlIaFg4JTjljU3VjkA)