# Why the ReturnType, one of the TypeScript's utility types returns `any` when the `inter R not equal to R`

Tags: typescript, type-inference, return-type

On [the TypeScript official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html),

```js
type MyReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (
  ...args: any
) => infer R
  ? R
  : any; // this 'any' can't be 'never'?
```

However, from the StackOverflow's other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63753551/typescript-returntype-is-any-if-parameter-type-is-never),
people sometimes put `never` instead of the last type `any` that you can see right next to the comment above.

From [typescript-challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges) on GitHub, on the `00002-medium-get-return-type.ts` file, it asks us to generate ReturnType without using it.

I solved it by putting type `never` at the end instead of `any`, but it didn't throw any errors.

Therefore my question is, **when does the last `any` type invoke actually, and why it can't be `never`?**

Answer (score 0):

I tested several cases, and figure out why.

```js
// case 1
type MyReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (
  ...args: any
) => infer R
  ? R
  : any;
type Test = MyReturnType<any>; // Test = any;

// case 2
type MyReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (
  ...args: any
) => infer R
  ? R
  : never;
type Test = MyReturnType<any>; // Test = unknown;
```

It is for when you put type `any` to the generic type `T`
The type `Test` returns `any` when `infer R ? R : any`, but it returns `unknown` when `infer R ? R : never` or `infer R ? R : unknown`

It is because from the type `any`, TypeScript cannot infer the `infer R`, so it falls back to the last condition which is `any`, but if the last condition is `never` or `unknonw`, it returns `unknown`.

---

In conclusion, I think maybe using `never` or `unknown` can be one other approach, as you are not legal to do anything with an `unknown` value. Because if you can't infer the return type of the `T`, it is not safe to make it as `any` and give all the freedom.

Still don't understand why `never` returns `unknown` though.

Please let me know if you know of any articles or information about it.

Happy Coding Y'all.